# CGRectContainsPoint problems

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

In my test game i have some sprites (**Bubbles** = NSMutableArray) wich are appear in random location at bottom of the screen.

I have **addBubble** and **spawBubble** methods:

```
- (void) addBubble {

CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]; 
bubbles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"bubbleSpriteList.plist"];
CCSpriteBatchNode *bubbleSpriteList = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"bubbleSpriteList.png"];
[self addChild:bubbleSpriteList];



bigBubble = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"bubble"];
[self addChild:bigBubble];
[bubbles addObject:bigBubble];


for (CCSprite *bubble in bubbles) {


    int minX = bubble.contentSize.width/2;
    int maxX = winSize.width-bubble.contentSize.width/2;
    int rangeX = maxX - minX;
    int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;
    bubble.position = ccp(actualX, 0);


    int minSpeed = 15.0;
    int maxSpeed = 20.0;
    int rangeSpeed = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
    int actualSpeed = (arc4random() % rangeSpeed) + minSpeed;


    ccBezierConfig bubblePath;
    bubblePath.controlPoint_1 = ccp(200, winSize.height/3);
    bubblePath.controlPoint_2 = ccp(-200, winSize.height/1.5);
    bubblePath.endPosition = ccp(0, winSize.height+bubble.contentSize.height/2);
    id bezierMove = [CCBezierBy actionWithDuration:actualSpeed bezier:bubblePath];

    [bubble runAction:bezierMove]; 
}}
-(void)spawBubble:(ccTime)dt {
[self addBubble];}
```

Then in my **init** method i added background and **spawBubble** method with random time interval

```
[self schedule:@selector(spawBubble:) interval:actualTime];
```

---

I'm trying to make every bubble from **Bubbles** blow, when it was touched, with this code

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
touchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:touchLocation];
touchLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:touchLocation];

for (CCSprite *bubble in bubbles) {
CGRect bubbleRect = CGRectMake(bubble.position.x - (bubble.contentSize.width/2), 
                                   bubble.position.y - (bubble.contentSize.height/2), 
                                   bubble.contentSize.width, 
                                   bubble.contentSize.height);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bubbleRect, touchLocation)) {            
        NSLog(@"%i", [bubbles count]);
        [bubble setDisplayFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"bubbleBlow"]];
        id disappear = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:0.1 opacity:0];
        [bubble runAction:disappear];            
    }
}

return TRUE;}
```

Every bubbles blowing perfectly if only one bubble in the screen, but if one bubble on the screen and another one was appeared, only last one is detects touches.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell without seeing more code - but here's where I'd start:

Above this line:

`for (CCSprite *bubble  in bubbles) {`

add:

`NSLog(@"%i", [bubbles count]);`

EDIT:

Based on the code you added:

Your problem is with this line:

`bubbles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

which is effectively wiping out your `bubbles` array every time you add a new bubble.

So, there will only ever be one bubble in the array - the last one.

Hence the problem you're running into.

Comment: So every time you add a bubble you're wiping out the bubbles array and creating a new one... that looks like your problem. `bubbles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` shouldn't be there - of should be encased in an `if (!bubbles)` or something similar.

Comment: @OnOff - Where do you initialize the bubbles array now? Or is it always nil now?

Comment: i gues problem in CGRectContainsPoint... I just removed bubbles array. Now it's just bigBubble ccSprite

Comment: @OnOff, No - you said a single bubble was working - and you had an obvious problem with your bubbles array - please show me where you're initializing the array now. Can you add a breakpoint to verify `bubbles` isn't nil now? if you removed the array how are you going to loop through them now?

Comment: my knowledges in objective c is not enough  to answer you )

Comment: @OnOff - it's not an objective-c question - it's a general programming question. You have a number of items and you need to test each of them - without storing them in an array how are you going to run your test against each of them?

Comment: @OnOff - You were doing a fine job before - you only had one minor mistake. If you go back to your original code and simply add: `if (bubbles != nil)` before `bubbles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` it would work.

Comment: ok, I will try to understand this mistake, 'couse not realy understanding it... thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I changed **addBubble**  methods by removing `bubbles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`, and adding it to **init** method...
Now everything works perfectly! )